# Linux - create user with no password (login without password prompt)

Tags: linux, password, passwd, shadow, autologin

I found many articles mentioning that user has no password after using `passwd -d`. While on some of my systems it indeed works (I can `su` from unprivileged accounts to them without giving password) on some systems it doesn't. I tried both `*` and empty but none of those works:

```
lapsio@pi-car1:~ $ sudo useradd potato -p '*'
lapsio@pi-car1:~ $ su potato
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
lapsio@pi-car1:~ $ sudo passwd -d potato
passwd: password expiry information changed.
lapsio@pi-car1:~ $ su potato
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
lapsio@pi-car1:~ $
```

Please note that I'm **not** talking about *empty* password (which can be set with empty string hash). I'm **not** talking about locking account either. I'm expecting situation where no `Password:` prompt appears at all in `su` and `getty` and **I am able** to log into that account instantly **without being asked for password** at all. It seems to work on older systems. Is there some system level configuration that controls this behavior?

To make it super clear I'm expecting following behavior:

```
lapsio@pi-car1:~ $ su potato
potato@pi-car1:~ $ #I'm potato user here, without being asked for password
```

Kind of like it works when you `su` from root except i want to be able to `su` from any unprivileged account as well. And log in from `getty` without seing password prompt, just like when you log in to root account on Arch liveCD for example.

Yes *I am aware* that it's terrible security practice and I'm aware of consequences of such practice but I still want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The PAM configuration for `su` is typically located at `/etc/pam.d/su` and it may refer to other files in the same directory using the `@include` directive. At some point, there will be a line that begins with `auth` and mentions `pam_unix.so`. In older distributions, it might include a `nullok` option that allows empty passwords; modern distributions usually use `nullok_secure`, which allows empty passwords only when the "authentication" is happening using one of the TTY devices listed in `/etc/securetty`.
Also, the implementation of the `nullok` option may vary.

In order to allow `su` to definitely allow access to a specific account without a password prompt, you might add a line like this:

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so quiet_fail user = potato
```

(**note:** spaces between `user`, `=` and `potato` are important!)

In order to take effect before `pam_unix.so`, and with the `su` command only, the line  should be placed in `/etc/pam.d/su` **before** any `@include` directives or other lines starting with `auth`.

However, creating a shortcut through `su`'s PAM configuration like this is a bit risky without first understanding how the PAM configuration is supposed to work in *your* unspecified Linux distribution. Test carefully before use.